# iPad orientation change with two xib.The previous object is not cleared

Tags: ipad, orientation

I am new to iPad/iPhone.i have a issue about the orientation change.

In my application i need to change the orientation.I create a two xib files for landscape an portrait mode.i create the object of the landscape view controller in portrait viewcontroller according to the orientation change and vice versa. I successfully achieved that orientation change in two view controllers. But the object of the previous view controller is not cleared.
For eg: when i change the orientation from a landscape mode to portrait mode the portrait view controller xib is loaded. when i click its close button the previous landscape view controller xib is loaded. I have to clear the previous landscape view controller xib.

Please help me.
Anyone please send me some sample codes.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's *View Controller Programming Guide* has [a section](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH7-SW9) on using separate view controllers for portrait and landscape. If you're targeting iOS 5.0+ you can use storyboards, and the implementation is pretty simple, with example code in the aforementioned link.

If not, you'll have to manage the creation & disposal of view controllers yourself, but if you have the iOS 4.3 SDK installed, there's a non-storyboard version of the same article, (AFAIK the 4.3 docs aren't on the web, but you can navigate to it in Xcode: iOS 4.3 Library > Cocoa Touch Layer > UIKit > View Controller Programming Guide > Custom View Controllers > Managing a View Controller's Interface Orientation > Creating an Alternate Landscape Interface).